# How to fix log4j vulnerability

Tags: security, gradle, logging, log4j, spring-boot-starter

I heard `Log4j` core is vulnerable according to https://spring.io/blog/2021/12/10/log4j2-vulnerability-and-spring-boot

So I need a fix to get rid of vulnerabilities from my services!

I am trying to bump up log4j from older versions to `2.15.0`

I can manually upgrade the dependencies but the problem is I don't know, is there any dependency that is downloading the log4j older version or not!

So I want some solution that will just upgrade the log4j dependency in my projects either they are direct or transitive :)

Comment: You can update log4j core dependency/jar with newer version. [log4j core 15](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.15.0) or [log4j core 16](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.16.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UPDATE] Log4j rolled out a new version `2.17.0` with some more security fixes and recommended using `2.17.0` in systems :)

[UPDATE]
Log4j released one more build which is `2.16.0` with one more security fix!

---

I found the dirty fix!

Just add the following code block in your build.gradle and this will upgrade your log4j libs to `2.16.0`

regardless of the dependency is direct or transitive

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'org.apache.logging.log4j') {
            details.useVersion '2.17.0'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do the first two "normal" solutions not work?

Comment: I wanted a quick solution without bothering with my code!

I tried other solutions but my test cases were failing! but this worked for me

Comment: How can we fix this vulnerability for Java 6 applications without upgrading the Java version?

Answer (score -3):

Please find the solution

> Upgrade Apache log4j version to 2.15.0 (released date: Friday,
> December 10, 2021) , if you are using Apache log4j and the version
> is less than 2.15.0.  Currently 2.15.0 is outdated. Use 2.16.0
>
> On Dec13th, apache has introduced new version of log4j - Log4j 2.16.0,
> this is more reliable to use.

Also check the JVM version, if lower than this may get impacted.

1. Java 6 – 6u212
2. Java 6 – 6u212
3. Java 7 – 7u202
4. Java 8 – 8u192
5. Java 11 - 11.0.2

Comment: Updating the Java version is not sufficient, it only protects you against some of the possible exploits. The only real fix is to update to log4j 2.16.0.

Comment: Thanks for the update, Yes my post was on Dec12th, log4j 2.15.0 was valid as of that date. log4j 2.16.0 was released on December 13th. also i have mentioned to updated the log4j version as well as the JVM version. Apache foundation has introduced log4j 2.17.0 version